# How to call a php function with variable in php

Tags: php, function

my function is

`Filter2($SearchQuery) ;`

when i use this function in page this function resuls to be displayed now i want print this function results whith a variable 
How to call a php function with variabl in php?

example :

```
$my_variabl = Filter2($SearchQuery) ;
echo $my_variabl;
```

Comment: Could you please post your actual function?

Comment: You make the function return a value instead of printing or echoing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every function in PHP has an option of a `return` value, and anything that you return is passed to whatever string is marked so

```
function xxx ($var){
///play with $var
$output = "this is a var: ".$var;
return $output
}

$parse = xxx($var); 
//
//$parse will now print "this is var: <value of var>";
//

print $parse;
```

This prints the value the function **returns** . If you get no return (void) from the function then there is no `return` inside the function code.

To view the full stats of what is given back, in the above example you can output more with:

```
var_dump($parse);
```

Comment: i cant use retun in Filter2 function

Comment: so your original question is basically saying "how can I print something that doesn't exist" ? Why can't you return from your function?

Comment: @ebrahim you can just add a line of `return true;` to simply return that the function was a success, you don't need to strictly return a variable.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you are not returning anything from your function

```
function Filter2($query){
    // do your work here
    // ..
    return "found it!";
}

$my_variabl = Filter2($SearchQuery) ;
echo $my_variabl;
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you get the value without returning from function? and your function does not include body part also.

```
function Filter2($SearchQuery){
   return " Result of Search Query";
}
$my_variabl = Filter2($SearchQuery) ;
print_r($my_variabl);
```